How to factor in skewness when multiplying distributions
I am trying to simulate compounding interest on an investment modeled as a distribution. In the interest of efficiency I want to do this directly, but to test I ran a monte carlo simulation to generate this graph

It is clear that the more multiplications I do the more right skewed the result gets, but I am having trouble figuring out how to calculate the resulting skew value. I have the return rate and the result represented as skewed normal distributions. If I understand correctly, it is usually not possible to calculate the product of these distributions, but I believe this is a special case where it is possible as I have seen a pretty clear relationship between the input skews and the product. Is there a functional way to compute the resulting skew? One thing I have observed is that as the years go on, the skew always increases, but by a smaller amount each time, and looks logarithmic when plotted.
.
Statistics is not my area so apologies for flawed nomenclature.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If each year's result is an i.i.d. lognormal random variable then you might see this sort of result.  If the skewness after $n$ years was close to $\left( \exp( n\sigma^2 ) + 2\right) \sqrt{\exp(n\sigma^2) - 1 }$ with $\sigma^2 \approx 0.007$ then you might see something like your second chart - it is not a logarithmic curve.
